# How to cancel recurring payment through paypal in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I implement recurrent payment in my website and it is working. But I am unable to cancel the subscription .

How to cancel paypal recurring subscription using codeigniter.

I have used this code :

```
 <form action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "post" id = "paypal_checkout">
<input type = "hidden" name = "cmd" value = "_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type = "hidden" name = "business" value = "' . $this->business . '"/>
<input type = "hidden" name = "no_shipping" value = "1">
<input type = "hidden" name = "a3" value = "' . $this->items[0]['price'] . '">
<input type = "hidden" name = "p3" value = "' . $this->items[0]['month'] . '">
<input type = "hidden" name = "t3" value = "M">
<input type = "hidden" name = "src" value = "1">
<input type = "hidden" name = "sra" value = "1">
<input type = "hidden" name = "item_name" value = "' . $this->items[0]['name'] . ' Package" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "lc" value = "' . $this->location . '" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "return" value = "' . $this->returnurl . '" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "cbt" value = "' . $this->returntxt . '" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "cancel_return" value = "' . $this->cancelurl . '" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "custom" value = "' . $this->items[0]['package_id'] . '" />
<input type = "button" name = "submit" />
</form>
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a standard subscription button, or are you using the recurring payments APIs to create the profiles?

Comment: @AndrewAngell  I am using the recurring payments API. For Ex.                    <input type = "hidden" name = "cmd" value = "_xclick-subscriptions">

Comment: That is not the recurring payments API.  That is a standard subscription button.  Unfortunately, those have no access to cancel via the API.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Is it possible to cancel via standard subscription button? If yes then how?

Comment: @AndrewAngell There is another way to cancel recurring payment via IPN  but I didn't get any idea about IPN.How to do that using IPN?

Comment: The only way to cancel profiles for standard subscriptions is to do it manually from within the PayPal account.  With recurring payments APIs there is an API available for canceling, and then you could do that within IPN (although that would be a little odd).

Comment: @AndrewAngell Is there any example available for recurring payment API for cancelling.

Comment: You would use the [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/) which is very simple (along with all the other PayPal APIs) using [this CodeIgniter PayPal library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter).